# How can optimize CPU usage for Springboot jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, cpu

My application is a runable jar file which is built from Spring-boot (using HikariCP, Hibernate/JPA), and is called from other application.
But it has got an issue : when it is called from other application, CPU usage of system sometimes up to > 90% (specially to 99%), CPU usage of JAVA up to > 70%.

About functional, it's a simple aplication, read file and do some simle business, upload file to AWS S3, connect to DB (by Hibernate/JPA).

I tried several different ways, but seem have not got solution.

I tried run with simple example as below link :
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-tutorial-with-hello-world-example/
But I complied above example, run it's jar file from console (cmd) then CPU usage of JAVA ( up to ~ 60%) and CPU usage of system (80%)
So, seem still high.

How can optimize CPU usage for Spring boot jar ?

Comment: Same way that you optimize any Java application. Measure, profile, identify hotspot, optimize hotspot, repeat.

Comment: But, with simple example (hello world), it still usage 60%. It's mean that problem is not in logic, isn't it ?

Comment: Any single threaded application that does something and then exits is liable to peak at 100% of CPU time during its life-time ... unless it is delayed by I/O or something like that.  What would be concerning is an application that uses 60% of CPU time over an extended period while doing essentially nothing.  But either way, unless you *investigate* what is using the CPU (by benchmarking, profiling, etc) you won't get to the bottom of the problem (real or imagined).   And we won't be able to help you either.

Comment: For what it is worth, with a Java application you need to consider the overheads involved in starting up the JVM, loading the application and all of the framework code that it depends on, JIT compilation, heap resizing and so on.  This can easily amount to multiple seconds of CPU time, depending on how large the application is.  But it is not insignificant even for a "hello world" application.  Java is notorious for slow startup.